# Display a property in a data template

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

There are the view models I want to display:

```
ClassA
{
  public ClassB b1 {get;set;}
  public ClassB b2 {get;set;} 
}

ClassB
{
   //...
}
```

I have a data template for `ClassA` and `ClassB` like this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type my:ClassA}">
  <Border DataContext="{Binding}" Padding="5" Margin="5" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
       <!-- invoke data template for "b1" -->
       <!-- here may be some other content -->
       <!-- invoke data template for "b2" -->
    </StackPanel>
  </Border>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type my:ClassB}">
   <!-- ... -->
</DataTemplate>
```

How can I say that I need a data template for properties `b1` and `b2` instantiated at the desired position?

I'm pretty sure that I have already seen something like this before, but can't remember where...

Comment: @close-voter: Why the vote for closing?? This is a perfectly valid question and even well explained and formatted!

Comment: I could have deleted the post (or abort the posting) but I thought it might be useful for someone else. It's also an opportunity for someone to post a better alternative. So I decided to "share your knowledge - Q & A style".

Comment: That's exactly what Stackoverflow is for! And that's why I did not understand why someone voted for closing your question. Keep the questions coming! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I remembered the solution ;-).

Short:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=b1}" />
```

Long:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type my:ClassA}">
  <Border DataContext="{Binding}" Padding="5" Margin="5" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
       <!-- invoke data template for "b1" -->
       <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=b1}" />

       <!-- here may be some other content -->
       <!-- invoke data template for "b2" -->
       <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=b2}" />
    </StackPanel>
  </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```